# Page with custom template make get request to a custom route - Pseudo code

Tags: query, rest-api

I created a page with a specific template and when the page load I would like it to make a get request to a custom route.
So far I am using JS and axios to make the request onload but I was wondering if there is an only PHP solution, kind of a new WP_QUERY but instead of args I just pass it the URL of my route ('/wp-json/custom/v1/custom/?term=myterm'.
Thank you for your help

Comment: if you are running the code on the same install could you not skip the route and call the function the route is calling directly? What's the problem you're trying to solve by doing this? Is this an attempt to optimise?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems so obvious after reading your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to retrieve data from that route and display that to the end user?

Instead of using the rest API to retrieve that information, you could put the callback function directly into your template file and then use the php $_GET variable ([php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)) to pass the search term into your function.
I think it would look like something like this:

```
 function output_data_from_search_term(){
  $url_param = $_GET['myterm'];
  if(empty($url_param)){
    echo "Search term missing, please try again.";
  }
  //Do whatever query you are doing in your custom rest api endpoint callback. 
  //Here is an example of getting the custom post types with that term and displaying the titles.
  $search_query = urldecode($url_param);
  $query_results = get_posts( array("post_type" => "custom-post-type", "s" => $search_query));
  foreach($query_results as $result){
    echo $result->post_title;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I should have thought about it!